# Expose a random port

Tags: docker

I'm using docker to deploy a software that uses a random RTP port. How can I EXPOSE a big range of ports? Can I possibly expose all ports of the docker Instance?

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in the Docker documentation.

Comment: While you wait for a solution, you can in newer version of Docker also use the host network.

`docker run --net=host ....` will make your container share the same network as the host it is on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently (Docker 1.0.1) not possible.

Other people have expressed strong interest in being able to expose and publish port ranges, and the Docker team is okay with that, see [here](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1834).

Some code has even been proposed (see pull request [here](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/4795)).

I guess it will be implemented soon, maybe get in touch with them to know if someone plans to work on that again.

Comment: It looks like Docker is going in the right direction then! Thanks. Sorry I can't up vote you yet.